# Modal Screen Post Result this Modal Screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I'm doing Post via Modal PopUp. I want to show the returned value again on the same Modal PopUp. How can I do that ?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(Param_Login login)
    {
        ViewBag.ResetPassword = true;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
        {
            new SqlParameter("EmailAdress",login.EmailAdress),
        };

        ds = DataManager.RunSP_ReturnDS("sp_Set_Web_ResetPassword", parameters);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ResultId"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            ViewBag.Hata = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Hata = true;
        }
        ViewBag.Mesaj = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ResultMessage"].ToString();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jquery ajax to avoid postback , and then retrieve the result in a partial view, replace the html in a div tag.

`$.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("ResetPassword", "ResetPassword")',
                    data: { dd: dd },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    traditional: true,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#div").html(response);
                    }
                });`